# preg_match not working on last two charcters

Tags: php, regex

i got his small code

```
 <?php  
    if (preg_match("/Remanufactured|REMANUFACTURED/",$product_info['products_description'] ) 
|| preg_match("/N2|N3|W1|W2|A1|A2|A3|R4/",$product_info['manufacturers_code'])) {
    echo "Refurbished";
   } else  {         
  echo "New Boxed"; 
 }
?>
```

if $product_info['manufacturers_code'] = '2122586R4' or 'MC-MCB43112U0C2/04/1' the above code works.

I want the above code to only match where the last two characters are "/N2|N3|W1|W2|A1|A2|A3|R4/"

i have tried "/N2$|N3$|W1$|W2$|A1$|A2$|A3$|R4$/" and it doesnt work.

regards

irfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
/N2|N3|W1|W2|A1|A2|A3|R4/
```

With

```
/^(.*)(N2|N3|W1|W2|A1|A2|A3|R4)$/
```

`.*` will match any string at the beginning and the specified two string at end

Comment: thanks it works.. i  will accept once 8 minutes past :)

Comment: @naf, There a modification in the answer. Please check the edited answer

Comment: @naf, With pleasure. Please up vote and accept when it is time. :)

Comment: /^.*(N2|N3|W1|W2|A1|A2|A3|R4)$/ doesnt work. but your orignal /.*(N2|N3|W1|W2|A1|A2|A3|R4)/  worked

Comment: @naf, I have checked and the code works fine in my side

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
preg_match('/(N2|N3|W1|W2|A1|A2|A3|R4)$/',$product_info['manufacturers_code'])
```

`( )` - Groups a series of pattern elements to a single element.

`|` - Separates alternate possibilities.

`$` - Matches the end of a line or string.

so "`(a|b)`" means "`a or b`". "`(a|b)$`" means "`a or b`" at the end of a line or string.

Comment: It's better practice to use single-quoted strings for regular expressions, so dollar signs won't resolve to variable values.

Comment: yeah, personally I use double-quoted strings only if I have to. Here I just copy-pasted topic starter's code.